# Solving Linear Recurrences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following recurrence:

$$a_n = 49 a_{n-2}, n \geq 2, a_0 = -8, a_1 = 14$$

I was able to derive the following:

When $n$ is even then, $a_n = -8(7^n)$, and for the odd values of $n$, $a_n = 2 (7^n)$.

How can I write this recurrence as a single equation?  (ex. $a_n = 2n^2$)

Comment: Do you want to know how to **write** it as a single formula, or how to **solve** it (you've already done that)?

Comment: I edited the question to rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a_n = 49 a_{n-2}$, the characteristic equation is $r^2=49$ which means $r=\pm 7$. So, the general solution is a linear combination of terms $7^n$ and $(-7)^n$. Applying the values for $a_0$ and $a_1$, you then end with $$a_n=-5 (-7)^n-3\ 7^n$$ you can rewrite in several different forms as shown by Alraxite.

Comment: How was -5 and -3 obtained?

Comment: Write $a_n=\alpha (-7)^n+\beta 7^n$ and compute $a_0$ and $a_1$. You have two equations for the two unknowns $\alpha,\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the sequence as $a_n=-8\cdot7^n$ for odd $n$ and $a_n=2\cdot7^n$ for even $n$ would be perfectly fine, but if you really want to combine them into a single expression, you could try:

$$a_n=-5\cdot((-1)^{n}+1)\cdot7^n+2\cdot7^n=7^n\cdot(-3-5\cdot(-1)^n)$$